# Twig, error on compare date

Tags: symfony, date, twig

If I try to compare date as this:

```
{% if (expireDate==NULL) %}
    {% if (date(expireDate) < date()) %}
        DANGER!
    {% elseif (date(expireDate) == date()) %}
        WARNING
    {% else %}
        DON'T WORRY
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}>
```

I assume that `date()` without params return the current date, and `expireDate` has a Date value.

My problem is that "WARNING" never been shown, and this mean that even if `expireDate` is today the `(date(expireDate) < date())` is always false.

Am I doing something wrong?

### UPDATE#1

This should works, but I don't know if it's correct.

```
{% if (expireDate==NULL) %}
    {% if (date(expireDate)|date('d-m-Y') < date()|date('d-m-Y')) %}
        DANGER!
    {% elseif (date(expireDate)|date('d-m-Y') == date()|date('d-m-Y')) %}
        WARNING
    {% else %}
        DON'T WORRY
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}>
```

Comment: is `expireDate` actually a date object?

Comment: Yes, came from a symfony2 Entity.

Comment: so you should be able to do `if (expireDate < date())`?  as expireDate is already a date object.

Comment: Ok, maybe I got it... `date(expireDate)|date('U')` is different from `date()|date('U')`... This mean that the comparison look at hours, minutes and seconds? Right?

Comment: Checkout the update #1

Comment: You'll have probleme because your test is a string comparaison so `"05/04/2015" < "27/03/2015"` give `false`

Comment: If I use `date()` I should compare date, no?

Comment: use US Format `Ymd` or `Y-m-d` if you want be sure of your test :)

Comment: You would make it easier for yourself, I suppose, if you would do as much as more of the logic in controller, and use twig mostly for presentation purposes.

Comment: That's a good idea! I thought that this could be easily possible on twig... Maybe I will do it on controller. Thanks!